# 2-Letter State Abbreviation Codes in VB

Tags: vb.net

Can anybody help i was given this at school and i really need help on it. It in Visual Basic 2010 Express. Question is to change states name to 2 Letter and calculate tax rate for them as well.

California retail customers (State code = “CA”) are charged a sales tax on purchases – the California tax rate is 10%.

Retail customers from New York (state code = “NY”) and Florida (state code = “FL”) are also taxed at a 5% tax rate.

I saw this on here but it doesn't seems to work for me:

```
if statename.tolower = "new york" then 
    statename = "NY"
else if
```

---

I was able to fill it in but it not working for me , am new to VB ... this is like my second work on it ... The input is from textbox which he said we should make sure when the state code is input the tax should be added to the total .

Public Class Form1

```
Public Class State
    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal abbr As String, ByVal taxPercent As Decimal)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Abbreviation = abbr
        Me.TaxPercent = taxPercent
    End Sub
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Abbreviation As String
    Public Property TaxPercent As Decimal
End Class
```

We are been told to use the

```
                         Try
                        Catch ex As Exception

                        End Try


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try

        Dim states As New List(Of State)
        states.Add(New State("California", "CA", 10))
        states.Add(New State("New York", "NY", 5))
        states.Add(New State("Florida", "FL", 5))

        For Each state As State In states
            Console.WriteLine("State: {0} Abbrevation: {1} Tax: {2}%",
                              state.Name, state.Abbreviation, state.TaxPercent)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

I really appreciate what you are doing sir , can you please explain to me how i should put this in the coding . The form name that am using is Form1 am trying to make it work then i can do a new project so that i will be able to understand it more better Thanks

---

Below is the full coding i have so far

Public Class Form1

```
Public Class State
    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal abbr As String, ByVal taxPercent As Decimal)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Abbreviation = abbr
        Me.TaxPercent = taxPercent
    End Sub
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Abbreviation As String
    Public Property TaxPercent As Decimal
End Class

Const U_P_S_DECIMAL As Decimal = 7D

Const SALES_TAX_RATE_SINGLE As Single = 0.1 '10 Percent Rate
```

This is the Private Sub

```
'declear module-level variables
Private TotalQuantityInteger As Integer
Private TotalSalesDecimal As Decimal

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try
        '5 percent salses tex rate
        Const SALES_TEX_RATE_SINGLE As Single = 0.05 '5 percent rate


        Dim states As New List(Of State)
        states.Add(New State("California", "CA", 10))
        states.Add(New State("New York", "NY", 5))
        states.Add(New State("Florida", "FL", 5))

        For Each state As State In states
            Console.WriteLine("State: {0} Abbrevation: {1} Tax: {2}%",
                              state.Name, state.Abbreviation, state.TaxPercent)
        Next

        'Declare variables
        Dim SubDecimal, SalesTaxDecimal, TotalDueDecimal, TotalCostDecimal, ShippingCostDecimal As Decimal
        'Declare variables and convert value from textbox controls to memory
        Dim PriceDecimal As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(PriceTextBox.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)
        Dim QuantityInteger As Integer = Integer.Parse(QuantityTextBox.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Number)

        'Process - Compute values
        'Subtotal = price times the quantity of books
        TotalCostDecimal = PriceDecimal * QuantityInteger

        'Sales tex = sales tax rate times the subtotal minus discount amount
        SalesTaxDecimal = Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(TotalCostDecimal * SALES_TEX_RATE_SINGLE), 2)

        SubDecimal = SalesTaxDecimal + ShippingCostDecimal

        'Total due is the subtotal minus discount amount plus sales tex
        TotalDueDecimal = TotalCostDecimal + SubDecimal

        If UPSRadioButton.Checked Then 'compute the shipping cost
            ShippingCostDecimal = U_P_S_DECIMAL * QuantityInteger
        End If


        'Output - display output formatted as currency
        SubtotalTextBox.Text = TotalCostDecimal.ToString("C")
        TotalDueTextBox.Text = TotalDueDecimal.ToString("C")
        salestaxTextBox.Text = SalesTaxDecimal.ToString("N")
        ShippingCostTextBox.Text = ShippingCostDecimal.ToString("N")

        'Accumulate total sales and total books sold
        TotalQuantityInteger += QuantityInteger
        TotalSalesDecimal += TotalDueDecimal
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

When am done with the form it should be just like this picture in this link

[IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/2cwjuhk.png[/IMG]

Comment: Why doesn't it work for you?   There are several ways to do this, and the code snippet you posted is one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a class to store the relevant informations of a `State`:

```
Public Class State
    Public Sub New(name As String, abbr As String, taxPercent As Decimal)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Abbreviation = abbr
        Me.TaxPercent = taxPercent
    End Sub
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Abbreviation As String
    Public Property TaxPercent As Decimal
End Class
```

Now you can fill a `List(Of State)`:

```
Dim states As New List(Of State)
states.Add(New State("California", "CA", 10))
states.Add(New State("New York", "NY", 5))
states.Add(New State("Florida", "FL", 5))
```

and you have all informations that you need encapsulated in a class, you don't need to fiddle around with string manipulation:

```
For Each state As State In states
    Console.WriteLine("State: {0} Abbrevation: {1} Tax: {2}%",
                      state.Name, state.Abbreviation, state.TaxPercent)
Next
```